# Can you and/or why should you not replace optocouplers with transistors when dealing with slightly different voltage

Tags: opto-isolator

I stumbled upon this:

[image]

[Source.](https://gyazo.com/9f495ed8e9005ab440db8061839f412a)

The MDB bus is communicating at a 34V level and the other side is at 5 or 3.3V.

Why are they coupled with optocouplers rather than a voltage divider on the master tx and a normal transistor on master rx?

What are some potential problems with such a design?

I am a layman at electronics so low level explanations would be great.

Comment: Using optocouplers is a safety consideration, most of the time.

Comment: That schematic is unreadable, and the site prevents me for looking at it in anything except their browser.

Answer (score 1):

You have optocouplers for both transmit and receive. The voltage difference by itself could be worked out with resistor dividers, or a simple transistor circuit if a boost in voltage is needed.

The reason optocouplers are widely used regardless of voltage differences is that they isolate grounds as well for galvanic isolation. You may have heard of 'ground loops' where the signal and/or Earth ground of different pieces of equipment are not the same.

Some equipment has an isolated ground, especially if powered by a wall-wart. Those with an isolated ground can have small non-hazardous leakage currents that may cause problems with data links, so using optocouplers isolates the "grounds" to prevent any ground loops.

Also equipment that is Earth grounded but at distant AC outlets may have enough current difference in their grounds to induce noise in direct coupled comm ports. Some ask you to run a separate signal ground from device to device to avoid drifts in a common 'signal' ground which often has a medium value resistor tied to Earth ground. RS-232 and RS-485 (multi-drop) ports have a signal ground shared by all connected ports, though it has a high impedance Earth ground by using a resistor high enough so it is only a 'static' reference.

I worked with surge generators for 15 years to simulate lightning strikes, and when it fired a 27,000 volt pulse at 20,000 amps our earth ground wire that went to an isolated ground rod had for a brief time (20uS) 1/2 of the surge voltage on it, or -13,500 volts on it. The oscilloscope had differential inputs and we used probes rated for 75KV, but we had to use an opto-isolator on the GPIB bus to the computer, or we could fry the GPIB card in the PC. We installed the isolator after 2 fried GPIB cards. At times the optocouplers save equipment from real damage.

Answer (score 0):

Normally optocouplers are used for galvanic isolation between circuits. So signals can be transmitted without any electrical connection.
In this case it could be the possible since we don't what the circuitry (and especially the 0V line) at the 36V part is doing.
Another reason to use optocouplers could be to avoid EMC issuses.
[LM2576](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2576.pdf) can switch up to 3A, these 3A are coming from the 36V part(since the LM2576 is a Buck Conveter) and so conduct through its ground line(0V). These high currents can rise the ground potential between other parts of the circuit(conductive coupling) and distort the signal integrity. This issue can be conquered by laying out seperate Power and Communication Grounds as its done here. So this optocouplers could be to avoid a ground loop bringing further EMC issues.

Answer (score 0):

Optoisolators are excellent for common-mode rejection. These are bi-directional optoisolators which give excellent immunity from isolating common mode noise.  This galvanic isolation offers many other benefits for HV isolation and transient protection.

The only down-sides are the tolerance on LED emissions and the GBW product limitations of the detector and possibly the CTR or current transfer ratio choice tradeoffs.

Answer (score 0):

Optocouplers are normally used for galvanic isolation.  The "connection" between the two sides of an optocoupler is just light.

The emitter and detector are physically separated inside the optocoupler, so no current can flow from one side to the other.  It would take a very high voltage to make current from one side "jump across" to the other side of the optocoupler.

The voltage required in the case of the [6N137](https://www.vishay.com/docs/84732/6n137.pdf) in the circuit is 8000V peak. Apply 8000 volts to one side of the optocoupler, and the other side won't notice it.

The thing is, though, that the circuit referred to in the question isn't using the optocouplers for galvanic isoation.

Both sides of the optocouplers use the same ground.  That breaks the galvanic isolation.  If you zap one side of that circuit with 8000 volts, both sides will "feel" the effects.

In the given circuit, both optocouplers could be replaced with transistor circuits that would be cheaper, simpler, and electrically faster than the optocouplers.